# jquery XML not working

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/

I am using a blogger xml feed but it won't work, could someone aid me as to where i have gone wrong or what is missing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) { 
    $(xml).find("entry").each(function () {
        $(".entirecont").append($(this).find('title').text());
    });
}
```

​

Comment: you need some kind of server side language to read and save xml on your server and then you can read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need jsonp data type to be able to access cross domain ajax call.
See the example below and check out what is jsonp in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser,
        dataType: "jsonp" // add this line
    });
});
```

hope it helps

UPDATES

Here is updated version of [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a domain out side of yours. Try creating a proxy on your server to retrieve the xml. Browser's don't allow for cross domain access in javascript.